# iMovie: How to add title with black background OVER video

Tags: macos, mac, imovie

I want to add simple title with black background while video is playing. All I've found that you can create title like a simple clip, and then use it in the beginning or the end... is that it =(? When you placing simple title over video, background becomes transparent, and I want it to become black.

Comment: Which iMovie verion?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but couldn't you just delete part of the video for however long you want the black background and put the black background before the video? Do you want the audio to play during the black background? There might be a way to separate the audio from the video and not delete the audio.

Comment: @None: I _think_ he wants a black box around/behind the overlay text only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the style of title you use. Only a couple of styles give the option to alter the background color. These styles are the following:

- Gradient - White
- Soft Bar - White
- Paper
- Formal
- Gradient - Black
- Soft Bar - Black
- Torn Edge - Black
- Torn Edge - Tan

You can find Apple's documentation here: [iMovie '11: Edit the text and appearance of a title](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2212?viewlocale=en_US)